# Getting started with ClojureScript and Google Closure

Tags: javascript, clojure, google-closure

I would like to investigate whether ClojureScript, with the associated Google Closure library is a reasonable tool to build modern, in-browser, Javascript applications.

My current Javascript stack consists of jQuery, Backbone and RequireJS with the possible additions of some widgets libraries like jQueryUI or KendoUI. So it will be quite a big leap (I already know how to work in Clojure, although I have little experience).

What is a good roadmap to do so? Should I learn the Google Closure library first, or can I grasp it together with ClojureScript?

One thing I am concerned about is the overall application structure. Backbone is rather opinionated on how to organize your application. I am not sure whether Google Closure also includes some components to help with the design of the application. And, if this is the case, I do not know how to tell whether this structure will port to ClojureScript or a ClojureScript application will require a different organization anyway, and only use - say - the widgets and DOM manipulation features of Closure.

Comment: What is the relationship between ClojureScript and Google Closure?

Comment: @GarrettHall: ClojureScript is a compiler for Clojure that emits JavaScript. Closure is a [Javascript to better Javascript compiler.](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) ClojureScript is designed to emit JavaScript code which is compatible with the advanced compilation mode of the Google Closure optimizing compiler.

Comment: Moreover, Google Closure also features a library, and that one is the suggested library in ClojureScript wiki. As they put it, it seems it is also used in the core.

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Google-Closure

Comment: What specifically do you have a question about?

Comment: Uh? The question is what I say in the text.Let me reword it. Would it be better to learn Google Closure as a Javascript library first? Would the overall organization of a Google Closure application port to ClojureScript? Or maybe it makes more sense to dive directly into ClojureScript and only use the pieces of Google Closure as I see fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say you have to sharpen your Clojure experience first, Google Closure after all is a JavaScript library and some other tools.

However, you need you check [ClojureScript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/):

> ClojureScript One will show you how ClojureScript reduces the complexity of web development by allowing you to write applications using one language to unify development across the client and the server

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above comments, but Rich Hickey goes into the relationship between ClojureScript and Google Closure tools in his intro of ClojureScript. http://blip.tv/clojure/rich-hickey-unveils-clojurescript-5399498

Basic gist is [in the comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139703/getting-started-with-clojurescript-and-google-closure?newsletter=1&nlcode=18924|ae92#comment263408_139703):

> ClojureScript is a compiler for Clojure that emits JavaScript ... and is design to emit ... code [that] is compatible with the advanced compilation mode of the Google Closure optimizing compiler.

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is why I asked the question in the first place. What I would like to know is if it makes sense to dive into ClojureScript directly and pick Closure along the way or if I should learn the library in JS first

Comment: That's a very judgement call. From my perspective, I'd go to ClosureScript and just pickup the Google Closure _Tools_ usage that was relevant as needed. I don't see how the rest of the Google Closure _Library_ is required to be part of it.